# Why doesn't mailto href work on safari iOS [11.3]?

Tags: ios, safari

We have angularjs application, recently we discovered that when you click on a `mailto` link safari does not open the email application. This works fine in chrome.

The example below doesn't seem to work on safari iOS 11.3.

```html
<a href="mailto:hello@world.com">Click me</a>
```

Instead, it throws the error below.

[image]

Anyone come across this issue or have a fix, please?

Comment: does your test device have it's mail app configured?

Comment: yes we have mail app configured